# Searching for a value of a parent array by a value of a nested array

Tags: mongodb

In my collection, I have counties. Every county has multiple cities. Each city has at least on zip code, but some has more.

So a county document (or object) looks something like this:

```
{
name: XYZ,
cities:
    [
    {name: ZYX,
    zipCodes: [{zip1:1234},{zip2:5678}]},
    {name: ZYX,
    zipCodes: [{zip1:4321},{zip2:8765}]}
    ]
}
```

I want to find the name of the city with a given zip code. For this, I tried the following query:

```
db.county.find({"cities.zipCodes.zipcode":1234},{"name":1, "_id":0});
```

But the result is all the city names in the county which has the given zip code. Even though the city's name which I'm looking for is in the list, I would like to receive only that city's name as the result.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Positional Operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/projection/positional/):

```
db.county.find({"cities.zipCodes.zipcode":1234},{"$.name":1, "_id":0});
```

Or

```
db.county.find({"cities.zipCodes.zipcode":1234},{"cities.$.name":1, "_id":0});
```

(While the latter seems more correct to me, I provided the former assuming that your initial query does what you say)

Comment: Thank you for your tip, but sadly none of the queries fetches any results for me.

Comment: Can you edit the question, adding a sample document, so that I can try fixing the answer?

Comment: Just did. In the light of this: do you think I should change the title of the question? I couldn't think of anythink better, but I'm not sure it describes my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After digging deep in the mongoDB reference, We've found the query I was looking for:

```
db.county.aggregate([
{$unwind : "$cities" }, 
{$unwind : "$cities.zipCodes" }, 
{$project: {countyName:"$name",
    cityName: "$cities.name",
    ZipCode: "$cities.zipCodes.zipCode",
    "_id":0}},
{$match:{"ZipCode":1234}
}]);
```

What I needed were the $unwind and the $match aggregate operators.

The first $unwind seperates the counties by cities, and the next seperates cities by zip codes. So there will be a seperate "document" for each zip code. After this, when I use the $match operator, it will only return fields from the array with the given zip code.